# How to center an image using NPOI with c#?

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel, npoi

I'm developing on a .net6.0 project and I have to generate and .xslx file using NPOI library and I need to add an image on a cell an center it.

So first of all I create a XSSFWorkbook, add a worksheet, a row and cells:

```
var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
var currentWorksheet = workbook.CreateSheet("MyWorksheet");

// Setting default width of my column
currentWorkSheet.SetColumnWidth(0, 600);

// Creating row
var currentRow = currentWorksheet.CreateRow(0);
currentRow.Height = 600;
```

Now I have my context, and I would like to add an image centered, therefore I added the image (base64string) doing :

```
// Converting base64string image in byte[]
var img = Convert.FromBase64String("MyBase64Image");

var pictureIndex = workbook.AddPicture(img, PictureType.PNG);
IDrawing drawing = currentWorkSheet.CreateDrawingPatriarch();

// Defining my image anchor
IClientAnchor anchor = drawing.CreateAnchor(200, 200, 400, 400, 0, 0, 0, 0);
anchor.AnchorType = AnchorType.MoveDontResize;
var picture = drawing.CreatePicture(anchor, pictureIndex);
picture.Resize();

// I want my image doing a specific size so i resize it :
var imageSize = picture.GetImageDimension();
double resizeX = 50.0 / imageSize.Width;
double resizeY = 50.0 / imageSize.Height;
picture.Resize(resizeX, resizeY);
```

But no matter what values I put in the

```
IClientAnchor anchor = drawing.CreateAnchor(200, 200, 400, 400, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

(except for the last 4) my image sticks to the top left of my cell. How do I center it in my cell ?

I tried to modify the values of dx1,dx2,dy1,dy2 of my anchor but no matter which values I use, the image stay in the same pot.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had this problem, too. And I solved it defining  anchor

```
        Dim anchor As XSSFClientAnchor = New XSSFClientAnchor();
        anchor.Col1 = colIndx;
        anchor.Col2 = colIndx + colCount;
        anchor.Dx1 = 0;
        anchor.Dx2 = anchor.Dx1 + img.Width;
        anchor.Row1 = rowIndx;
        anchor.Row2 = rowIndx + rowCount - 1;
        anchor.Dy1 = 0;
        anchor.Dy2 = anchor.Dy1 + img.Height;
```

Always mention to add the images as last after put together the sheet data, the sizes of all rows and columns have to be adjusted  before drawing an image. That was the problem I have dealed with for hours.